# Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement. angular 10

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

t get this message : 'Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement'

```
if (isDefined(this.#Type.externalControls)){
  this.#Type.externalControls = this.#Type.externalControls.sort(sortFn);
  this.#Type.externalControls.forEach((control: ITypeControl) => {
    externalForm.push(new FormControl(control));
  });
}
```

please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What `.sort` does is, it sorts the array it's called on *in place*, and then returns that array. Assigning the return value of `.sort` to a new variable could well cause confusion, because now you (may) have *two* references to the same exact (now sorted) array, rather than a reference to a sorted array and a reference to an unsorted array.

That is

```
const arr = getArr();
const sortedArr = arr.sort();
```

is confusing, because `arr === sortedArr`.

The warning is telling you to not use the return value of `.sort`, to avoid confusing yourself. Change

```
this.#Type.externalControls = this.#Type.externalControls.sort(sortFn);
```

to

```
this.#Type.externalControls.sort(sortFn);
```